# Detect Delete/Insert/Update in MatView Refresh Concurently

Tags: postgresql, replication, materialized-view

I have a matview which I refresh once in a hour.(50M rows). By running

```
refresh materialized view concurently my_view;
```

Note - MatView contains a unique Index too, on column `unique_id`.

I have a table `mirror_table` which is a copy of `my_view`. How I can keep this `mirror_table` in sync with the matview after the refresh query?

I can detect deletions and insertion by
Delete - Unique ID Present in `mirror_table` but not in `my_view`;
Insert - Unique ID Present in `my_view` but not in `mirror_table`;

How to detect **updates** ?